# How should I handle a split in a retopology?

Tags: mesh, vertices, topology

**What's the best way to handle a "split" in retopology?** Consider the case of a torso splitting into legs:

[image: A torso with two legs below it; there is a gap separating the two.]

In this case, each leg ring is made up of 16 vertices, as is the torso ring. What is the best way to attach these together with clean topology to create a good retopo?

This also applies to standard mesh modeling: **what's the best way to create such a split with polygon manipulation?**

Comment: Are triangles ok? If you are making this for a lowpoly model (computer game), triangles are ok. If you are going to subdivide it, they are not (probably).

Comment: @Gunslinger it will be subdivided.

Comment: it makes things more complicated but my answer below should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First step. Make flaps bending down between the legs.

[image: Step1]

Make a strip between them and make several loop cuts. You may have to experiment to find the correct number of loop cuts. This is important if you want to have an all quad model. The total number of edges around the opening must match the leg.

[image: Step2]

Round out the strip to match the correct shape.

[image: Step3]

Select the two loops and bridge them. If you have the correct number of loop cuts in the strip between the flaps, this should be all quads. Else you will get triangles.

[image: Step4]

Further adjust the geometry to make the bridged area more even.

[image: Step5]

Final result:

[image: Step6]

Comment: Very clean. Nice.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would do it to maintain Quads, and hence good edge flow.
As you see I did it in half first, always easier than repeating yourself.

[image]

Comment: I dont think that your edge flow is all good. Around the diamond shapes it will go vertical, around the diamond, around the leg horisontal, around another diamond and then shift down. It will be hard to make additional loopcuts on some places. Also, the face loop will follow the same pattern in some places (up, around and down).

Comment: @Gunslinger: even so, the answer describes the work-flow quite well, and the user can tweak the edge flow to their liking.