# How to close an open manifold?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I made a 3D scan of one of my wife's sculptures, but I'm having trouble closing off the open ends. I want something sculptural (positive curvature in some places, negative in others), but how to close the shape for further digital sculpting?

[image: Top part of my wife's "Female Vessel #1" sculpture.]

Comment: I would just merged vertices at border of hole into one in center, end sculpted there with dynotopo enabled.

Comment: @X-27 Even though requesting tutorials is out of scope for this site, it might be better if you explain that in a more constructive way.  What you wrote sounds very hostile.

Comment: Obviously this model needs a lot of clean-up work before that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could select the edges on the border using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB [image]</kbd> in *Edit Mode*. Press space to show the popup menu and type *Grid Fill*.

[image]

If you want the filled area flat you can scale the z-axis <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

[image]

In order to edit a high poly mesh in Blender created by sculpting or importing 3D-scans usually retopology is required.

Related:

- [How should I handle a split in a retopology?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/how-should-i-handle-a-split-in-a-retopology)
- [Is there a way to "rescue" mesh that has very bad topology?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18203/is-there-a-way-to-rescue-mesh-that-has-very-bad-topology/18204#18204)